# Redirect user if record doenst exist in database

Tags: mysql, redirect

I'm working on a small php script which call records from databse.
I'm using this code :
`
mysql_query("select * from kalimat where cat=$id order by id");

`
I want to redirect user to 404 error page if the cat id doesnt exist in the database !

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:-

```
$name = mysql_query("select * from kalimat where cat=$id order by id");
if (!$name) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    die();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem which you get in this??

Comment: No Problem ! I receive A normal page but with no result because i have just 28 rows in databse and im using $GET_['id'] to use it in where :) the problem is i want to redirect users that have an records that dont exist in db

Comment: I am sorry but I didnt get your point. P.S.:- Did you include the error page in your current page and send a 404 error status code??

Comment: @checkopenport:- Changed with the error code. Does that help??

Comment: look i have html page called index.php and i use the mysql query code in another php file which i include in it did you get this ?

Comment: Try to include the error page in your current page and send a 404 error status code

Comment: I hope that this is not the problem:- **Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.** [1]:http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: aha ! In my case the header is not used at first of file ! i use it in middle !

Comment: What is the solution ?